# How to insert simple string with ' char into oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, insert

So my problem is that i need to insert company names into some database. It works fine but when i try to insert, for example Mc'Donalds it doesnt work because it finds end before the real end. So when i try that:

```
Inert into mydatabase (name, adress) values ('Mc'Donalds', 'somewhere')
```

It crashes. Is there some char like  \ to ignore it? Thank u!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To escape reserved chars like `'`, you'll probably want to double the apostrophe character. See http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries

Answer (score 3):

To be complete, you can also use the q function : `q'[Mc'Donalds]'`

See also this blog entry:
http://www.talkapex.com/2009/03/q-function-escape-single-quotes.html

Answer (score 0):

```
   DECLARE
    VA_SQL_MSJ VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    VA_SQL_MSJ:='INSERT INTO A_PRUEBA (B) VALUES (1)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VA_SQL_MSJ;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: I don't see a `'` character to escape _inside_ the string here.